# evil rectangles with point past EOL

Tags: evil, rectangle

When visually selecting rectangles with <kbd>C-v</kbd> in `evil`, the point is not allowed to pass the end of line.

This is in contrast with:

- `rectangle-mark-mode`
- `cua-rectangle-mark-mode`

Both of which allow the point to pass the EOL. (Although `evil`s behavior is correct `vim` emulation)

Is there any way I can bring this functionality to evil?

Comment: Does the behaviour change if you customize `evil-move-cursor-back` or `evil-move-beyond-eol`?

Comment: @wasamasa no, sadly. `evil-move-beyond-eol` only lets you move one character past eol. :/

Comment: I'm pretty sure there was another question mentioning Evil and overlays as a possible solution for this problem...

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible with evil. In [colemak-evil](https://github.com/patbl/colemak-evil/blob/master/colemak-evil.el) it seems there is an option for  `set = virtualedit=block`  (which in vim does exactly you are asking) but I was not able to implement. So the only option is to switch to Emacs state and use rectangle-mark-mode as you already stated.

Comment: Judging by cua-rect.el ` (I couldn't get `rectangle-mark-mode` to do the right thing) this is possible to do by adding a `cursor` property with a number indicating the place where the cursor should be inside the string used as `after-string` for the overlay making up the final line of the rectangle.

Comment: What I'm more concerned about is teaching Evil that the otherwise inaccessible areas (be it tabs in indentation or places after the line) are to be taken into account.  Perhaps it's as simple as either replacing tabs with spaces or adding spaces until the previously unreachable point, then performing the rectangle operation.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off creating an evil key map for one of the rectangle modes.

The macro evil-define-key allows you to bind to key maps in evil style.

```
(evil-define-key 'normal key-map-name "key" 'function)
```

Also you can add binding to the evil global map,

```
(evil-global-set-key 'normal "key" 'function)
```

You may like this hydra for use with rectangle-mark-mode, which will work in a similar way to evil / vim.

http://oremacs.com/2015/02/25/rectangle-hydra/

I'd recommend you play with the different rectangle modes and decide which one you like best, and then make the key map bindings as you need them / see fit. There's also https://github.com/zk-phi/phi-rectangle - Personally I use CUA Rectangle mode, it has a lot of features, although I think navigational bindings are a bit strange/inconsistent.

It's also up to you how you decide to invoke whichever rectangle mode, one option I think makes sense is to have it available in the Visual mode map.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: @PythonNut I can add more detail if you need it.